# fscanf always returns 0(CLOSED)

Tags: c, scanf

I am a beginner in C programming, and I am trying to write a simple code to read a text file and write its content into an array, then print it on console. However, I always get 0.0000, and I could not solve the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numOfLines(FILE *fp1);
void printarr(float arr[], int size);
float *filetoArr(FILE *fp, int arrsize);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *fileName1 = argv[1];
    FILE *fp1 = fopen(fileName1, "r");
    printf("File name: %s", fileName1);
    int size = numOfLines(fp1);
    printf("Number of lines in the file: %d\n", size);
    float *arr = filetoArr(fp1, size);
    printarr(arr, size);
    free(arr);
    fclose(fp1);
}

void printarr(float *arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%f ", *(arr + i));
    }
}

float *filetoArr(FILE *fp, int arrsize) {
    int size = arrsize;
    float *arr = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%f\n", (arr+i));
    }
    return (arr);
}

int numOfLines(FILE *fp1) {
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    char c;
    do {
        c = getc(fp1);
        if (c == '\n') {
            numberOfLines++;
        }
    } while (c != EOF);
    return numberOfLines;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not checking the return value from `fopen`

Comment: *"fscanf always returns 0"*... but you never check the return value from `fscanf`. What is it? The number of items successfully scanned.

Comment: What is the purpose of `\n` in `fscanf` format string? What were you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: `getc` returns an `int` intentionally. A `char` cannot represent `EOF` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `numOfLines` goes to the end of the file.

You have to `rewind(fp1)` to reset your file handle to position 0, or `fscanf` hits the end of the file, and doesn't read anything (check return code from `fscanf`: it should be 1 I bet you're getting 0 all the time)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you read the whole file in `numOfLines()`: you must reset the file pointer to the beginning of file with `rewind(fp1);` so `fscanf()` can read the file instead of hitting the end of file immediately.
- the variable `c` used to read bytes from the file must be defined as an `int` for the test for end of file to be reliable. Otherwise, depending on whether `char` is signed or not by default, the `EOF` would never match or could potentially match the character `\377` as end of file erroneously.
- you do not check for failure to open the file.
- Although returning 0 is implicit for function `main()` since C99, it is advisable to write the `return 0;` statement explicitly for better clarity.

Comment: "main() should return 0 for complete portability." What exactly is meant here by "complete portability"? If you mean portability to outdated versions of language standard (C89/90), then mid-block variable declarations should also be avoided. Or is it something else?

Comment: OK, I rephrased my remark. IMHO omitting the `return 0;` is sloppy.

Comment: One might argue that in that case it should be `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` for better clarity :) I'd say that for programs that don't actively manage their completion code omitting the explicit `return` is perfectly fine. On the other hand, this specific program should probably manage its completion code: it should check whether `fopen` succeeded and return `EXIT_FAILURE` in case of failure.

Comment: If failure is returned, `EXIT_FAILURE` seems appropriate, and for consistency, `EXIT_SUCCESS` would make sense. Otherwise, `return 0;` is fine. The exit status is documented in the C Standard this way: *If the value of status is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.*